# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I want all the functions to return a single numerical quantity but when printing the result gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Servio/Desktop/TravelTrue.py", line 64, in <module>
  print 'Its total investment is',costo_viaje(ciudad, model, dias, otros_gastos, noches) ,"$ , ", " Suerte!"

File "C:/Users/Servio/Desktop/TravelTrue.py", line 59, in costo_viaje
  return type_auto(model) + alquiler_de_auto(dias) + costo_hotel(noches) + costo_del_vuelo(ciudad) + otros_gastos

File "C:/Users/Servio/Desktop/TravelTrue.py", line 41, in alquiler_de_auto
  costo = costo - 100 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

The code is

```
def costo_hotel(noches):

    return 140 * noches

def costo_del_vuelo(ciudad):

    cities = {
        "Cordoba": 821,

        "Iguazu": 941,

        "Ushuaia": 1280,

        "Bariloche": 1848,

        "Palermo": 1242,

        "Francia": 6235,

        "Yugoslavia": 2125,

        "Vietnam": 2532,

        "Buenos Aires": 2499,

        "Montevideo": 2129,

        "Mexico": 1499,

        "Moscu": 3499,

        "Maracaibo": 4499,

        "Irak": 9998,

    }

    return cities[ciudad]


def type_auto(model):
    costo_type = model
    if model == "deportivo":
        costo_type = 860
    elif model == "familiar":
        costo_type = 345
    return costo_type


def alquiler_de_auto(dias):
    costo = dias * 338
    if dias >= 7:
        costo = costo - 100
    elif dias >= 3:
        costo = costo - 50
    return costo

model = raw_input("Que modelo de auto llevara?")

noches = raw_input("Cuantas noches estara en el hotel?")

dias = raw_input("Cuantos dias tendra el auto?")

ciudad = raw_input("A que ciudad viajara?")

otros_gastos = raw_input("Gastos Generales?")



def costo_viaje(ciudad, model, dias, otros_gastos, noches):
    return type_auto(model) + alquiler_de_auto(dias) + costo_hotel(noches) + costo_del_vuelo(ciudad) + otros_gastos 

print 'Its total investment is',costo_viaje(ciudad, model, dias, otros_gastos, noches) ,"$ , ", " Suerte!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an operand with incompatible types. For example, if I have the following:

```
x = 3
fruit = "apples"
```

I cannot do,

```
print(x + fruit)
```

because their types are different - one is an integer, the other string. When coercing (casting) the variable into another type like so:

```
print(str(x) + " " + fruit)
```

They are now both string and compatible, and 3 becomes "3". The statement will successfully print out:

```
3 apples
```

Note: when doing str(x), the variable x still stays an integer, but str(x) returns a string.

So, in the function

```
alquiler_de_auto(dias)
```

You are multiplying `dias` by an integer, but `dias` is not an integer - `dias` is a string because `raw_input()` always returns a string. You could do `int(dias)` to change the string to an integer thus making them compatible types.

Comment: I would add that str(x) returns a string version of the object x while x itself remains an integer.

Comment: So...
I think I've solved tranformando in "int " 3 of 5 : Functions
The number needed to enter
But , so , raw_input chains will always ask ? Then this well transform in int, or str, it depends on the argument:

Comment: {model = raw_input("Que modelo de auto llevara?")

noches = int(raw_input("Cuantas noches estara en el hotel?"))

dias = int(raw_input("Cuantos dias tendra el auto?"))

ciudad = raw_input("A que ciudad viajara?")

otros_gastos = int(raw_input("Gastos Generales?"))}